# trying to clone form field but the last field (family ) doesn't show up. I am new to programming and don't know what i am doing wrong

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <input type="text" value="Employee" name="employee" class="clonedInput1" id="logical1"/>
    <div class="slds-form-element__row clonedInput" id="condition1">
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
        <div class="status1" name="status1"><h2>Single</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
         <input type="number" class="employeeStepper" min="0" max="1500" value="0" name="stepper1"/>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
          $<input type="text" id="input-01" name="amount1"/>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
         $<input type="text" id="input-02" name="amount2"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-form-element__row clonedInput2" id="logical2">
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
        <div class="status2" name="status2"><h2>Family</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
         <input type="number" class="employeeStepper" min="0" max="1500" value="0" name="stepper2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
          $<input type="text" id="input-01" name="amount3"/>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4" name="ratio">
          Ratio:
         <select>
             <option value="1:1">1:1</option>
             <option value="1:2" selected="">1:2</option>
             <option value="1:3">1:3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="slds-form-element__row">
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
         <div class="status" name="status2"><h2>With Family</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
         <input type="number" id="employeeStepper" min="0" max="1500" value="0" name="stepper2" />
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4">
          $<input type="text" id="input-01" name="amount3" />
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-4" name="ratio">
          Ratio:
         <select>
             <option value="1:1">1:1</option>
             <option value="1:2" selected="">1:2</option>
             <option value="1:3">1:3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div> -->
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDele" value="Del" />
  </div>
  </div>

Here is my JQuery....
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var num1     = $('.clonedInput1').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var num2     = $('.clonedInput2').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added (single input)
                var newNum1  = new Number(num1 + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added (employee)
                var newNum2  = new Number(num2 + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added (family input)

                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#condition' + num).clone().attr('id', 'condition' + newNum);
                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem1 = $('#logical' + num1).clone().attr('id', 'logical' + newNum1);
                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem2 = $('#logical2' + num2).clone().attr('id', 'logical2' + newNum2);

                // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum1).attr('name', 'name' + newNum1);
                // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum2).attr('name', 'name' + newNum2);

                // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
                $('#condition' + num).after(newElem).after(newElem1);
                // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
                //$('#logical' + num1).after(newElem2);

                // enable the "remove" button
                $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','');

                // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                if (newNum == 25)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                if (newNum1 == 25)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                if (newNum2 == 25)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDele').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var num1 = $('.clonedInput1').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var num2 = $('.clonedInput2').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#condition' + num).remove();     // remove the last element
                $('#logical' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','disabled');
                if (num1-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDele').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! To get good answers, I think you might need to be a bit [more precise about what you want to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far? What result has that produced? How would the result you want to have look?

Comment: Thanks for your response Maximillian, i'll try to be more specific next time. Actually figured out what was wrong with my code. Thanks again for helping new developers like me:)